# "Consume or put back" Go channels

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to have two separate consumer go routines, that would filter out even and odd numbers from the input channel. This is just a toy example in order to see if it is possible to have consumers do something with the message read from the input channel if it matches certain condition, otherwise put back onto the input channel.

My current code is as follows:

```
package main

func filterOdd(ch chan int, out chan int) {
    val := <- ch
    if val % 2 == 0 {
        ch <- val
    } else {
        out <- val
    }
}
func filterEven(ch chan int, out chan int) {
    val := <- ch
    if val % 2 != 0 {
        ch <- val
    } else {
        out <- val
    }
}

func main() {
    even := make(chan int)
    odd := make(chan int)
    input := make(chan int)
    go filterOdd(input, odd)
    go filterEven(input, even)
    for i:=1; i <= 10; i++ {
        input <- i
    }

    println("Even...")
    for i := range even {
        println(i)
    }

    println("Odd...")
    for i := range odd {
        println(i)
    }
}
```

However, this produces the following output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox594577124/main.go:27 +0x140

goroutine 4 [chan send]:
main.filterOdd(0x10336100, 0x103360c0)
    /tmp/sandbox594577124/main.go:8 +0xc0
created by main.main
    /tmp/sandbox594577124/main.go:24 +0xc0
```

Link to the Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9RIvFsGKI-

Comment: @ZanLynx: while this question says they got a deadlock in their sample code, it doesn't sound like they are trying to do the same thing as in that other question.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Of course not the same thing. But it looks like the general problem and solution are identical for this question.

Comment: And I just noticed even if you fix the buffering your for loops are not in goroutines and will therefore block unless you always make your buffers larger than your loop size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a deadlock because your even and odd goroutines are blocked on sending to `out` because nothing is reading from it. Why is nothing reading `out`? Because the `main` goroutine is blocked on sending to `input` because nothing is reading from it. Why is nothing reading from `input`? Because the two goroutines that would read from it are blocked.

Also, both `filterEven` and `filterOdd` will only run once unless you wrap their contents in `for { }` (but then they'll never stop until you `break`). On the other hand, `range even` will block (and `range odd` never happens) when nothing is left to write to `even` , because `range` over a channel only stops when the channel is closed or `break` is called.

In general, these aren't hard problems to solve as long as you know when you can close a channel. With what you're describing, that gets more difficult. None of the goroutines know when it's OK to close `input`, because all three write to it and two also read from it. You can use a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to make sure that everything you've put into the `input` channel has been processed before closing it. Once it's closed, the two other goroutines can use that as a signal to close their own channels and `break` or `return` to finish running.

However, writes to the `in` and `out` channels will still block until there is a corresponding read, because they are unbuffered. However, if you buffer them by specifying a size as the second argument to `make`, writes won't block until the channel is full. Since you know neither `even` or `odd` will have more written to them than what `main` send to `input`, you can use that as a safe buffer capacity.

Here's an example of using a `WaitGroup` with buffered channels for your code: https://play.golang.org/p/VXqfwUwRcx

If you don't want buffered channels, you can also use another pair of goroutines to capture the values and send them back to `main` as slices once finished. This way writes on the `even` and `odd` channels don't block: https://play.golang.org/p/i5vLDcsK1v

Otherwise, if don't need to print the contents of each channel all at once, you can use those two extra goroutines to read from the channels and print right away: https://play.golang.org/p/OCaUTcJkKB